# Qt Creator won't build

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have been tasked with converting a project that was built in QtCreator to .NET

The first thing I am trying to do is build the project in QtCreator so that I can step thru its execution to follow the flow and see some of the variables at play (real values).

When I build, I get a lot of errors like this:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QFrame': No such file or directory
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QMainWindow': No such file or directory
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QSpinBox': No such file or directory
```

When I search my drive, I do find 'QFrame', but in paths that have things like this in them:

```
android_armv7
msvc2013_64
winphone_x86
winrt_x64
```

Here is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG *= warn_on
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): CONFIG *= console

QT += widgets

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Source Files
#------------------------------------------------------------

FORMS += \
    GUIDemo.ui \
    Registration.ui \

HEADERS += \
    CustomFrames.h \
    GUIDemo.h \
    MultiRadar.h \
    QControlUtils.h \
    ScannerInfo.h \
    TabAdvanced.h \
    TabBScan.h \
    TabGuardZone.h \
    TabImage.h \
    TabInstallation.h \
    TabPPI.h \
    TabTargets.h \

SOURCES += \
    CustomFrames.cpp \
    GUIDemo.cpp \
    MultiRadar.cpp \
    QControlUtils.cpp \
    ScannerInfo.cpp \
    TabAdvanced.cpp \
    TabBScan.cpp \
    TabGuardZone.cpp \
    TabImage.cpp \
    TabInstallation.cpp \
    TabPPI.cpp \
    TabTargets.cpp \
    main.cpp \

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Include directories
#------------------------------------------------------------

INCLUDES = \
    ../../include \


#------------------------------------------------------------
# UI Generation
#------------------------------------------------------------

CONFIG(debug,   debug|release): TARGET_DIR = debug
CONFIG(release, debug|release): TARGET_DIR = release

UI_DIR = GeneratedFiles
MOC_DIR = $${UI_DIR}/$${TARGET_DIR}
INCLUDEPATH += $${UI_DIR}

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Libraries
#------------------------------------------------------------

LIBS += \
    -L../../lib/$${TARGET_DIR} \
    -lNRPClient \
    -lNRPPPI \

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Final config
#------------------------------------------------------------

#set the qmake variables
DEPENDPATH += $$INCLUDES
INCLUDEPATH += $$INCLUDES
```

The folder indicated by INCLUDES is there and contains a bunch of project-specific header files.

I have a feeling that I am missing some part of QtCreator that would allow me to build for Win7.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your project's .pro file?

Comment: Also check if that old project was on some older version of Qt and uses `QtSingleApplication` or some other classes which aren't part of the Qt5 versions.

Comment: .pro file added to OP

Comment: I am assuming that the project you have was developed and built on an older version of Qt, probably Qt 4.x. Check one of the project's header files and see of the includes are something like `#include <QtGui/QFrame>` instead of `#include <QFrame>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Qt Creator** is just the IDE. You need to have installed the **Qt libraries** as well, so make sure you have them.

These errors suggest that the project's **.pro** file should add the `widgets` module:

```
QT += widgets
```

This makes sure the project includes the right include directories (the ones that have QFrame and such)  and library directories on Qt 5.x.

**EDIT:**

After a little bit of chat, we discovered that Qt SDK for MS2010 was installed, but since the OP had MS2013 on his box, what solved the problem was downloading and installing Qt SDK for MS2013.

Comment: Ok, I addeded 'QT += widgets' to the .pro file right after the 'CONFIG' lines. No joy.  How do I make sure I have the Qt libraries installed (properly). I installed with something called qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.6.0-4-online.exe

Comment: Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions

Comment: After changing the .pro file, don't forget to **Run qmake** again.

Comment: It says I have Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 64bit and MSVC2010 OpenGL 32bit. Good?  How do I run Qmake?  I read a thread that indicated a Rebuild All would do it, but after a Clean All and a Rebuild All, I still have the same errors.

Comment: @davecove: right click on the project and then run qmake, but yeah, rebuild all should have just worked.

Comment: The problem is that you have a 32bit compiler trying to build an application with 64bit libraries. You must install Qt 32bit libraries!

Comment: When I look at my kits, it says that 'Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2010 OpenGL 32bit (default)'. Doesn't that mean I am using the 32bit libraries?  Also, why does it mention VS2010?

Comment: You realize you just gave us 2 different answers, right? Anyway, you downloaded Qt SDK for MS2010. But if you have MS2013 installed, you need to download Qt SDK for MS2013.

Comment: I uninstalled Qt and pulled down the VS2013 32bit installer. Now my .pro file builds.